# Hoy can I get from Analytics API User Explorer and User Report

Tags: google-analytics, report, analytics, explorer

I need to catch from a website, the list of users (IDs from User Explorer) that has been entered each day, and all the report from each one (User Report)

I didn't see anything about it in the current API from Google Analytics. Someone knows how to get it?

I saw some questions but from more than 1 year ago, someone knows if there is now any new?

The only thing that I can do for now, is using the automatic report from Google Analytics via email, and send me a report each day with a list of Client IDs en CSV, but I need the report...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Capture the Google Analytics Client ID or user id in a custom dimension and hit timestamp. Then you can recreate the user explorer id report yourself using the Google Analytics Reporting API.